# Button not apear in android device but shown in corona simulator and mobogini

Tags: android, sockets, lua, coronasdk

In corona simulator and genymotion I can see the buttons, but on the android device I don't see anythings
and there is no errors in console.
this is  main.lua and server.lua , please help me to fix my problem

main.lua

```html
local S = {}

local socket = require( "socket" )

local clientList = {}
local clientBuffer = {}

S.getIP = function()
    local s = socket.udp()
    s:setpeername( "74.125.115.104", 80 )
    local ip, sock = s:getsockname()
    print( "myIP:", ip, sock )
    return ip
end

S.createServer = function()

    local tcp, err = socket.bind( S.getIP(), 1235 )  --create a server object
    tcp:settimeout( 0 )

    local function sPulse()
        repeat
            local client = tcp:accept()  --allow a new client to connect
            if client then
                print( "found client" )
                client:settimeout( 0 )  --just check the socket and keep going
                --TO DO: implement a way to check to see if the client has connected previously
                --consider assigning the client a session ID and use it on reconnect.
                clientList[#clientList+1] = client
                clientBuffer[client] = { "hello_client" }  --just including something to send below
            end
        until not client
        
        local ready, writeReady, err = socket.select( clientList, clientList, 0 )
        if err == nil then
            for i = 1, #ready do  --list of clients who are available
                local client = ready[i]
                local allData = {}  --this holds all lines from a given client

                repeat
                    local data, err = client:receive()  --get a line of data from the client, if any
                    --print(data )
                    if data then
                        allData[#allData+1] = data
                    end
                until not data

                if ( #allData > 0 ) then  --figure out what the client said to the server
                    for i, thisData in ipairs( allData ) do
                        print( "thisData: ", thisData )
                        --do stuff with data
                    end
                end
            end

            for sock, buffer in pairs( clientBuffer ) do
                for _, msg in pairs( buffer ) do  --might be empty
                    local data, err = sock:send( msg )  --send the message to the client
                end
            end
        end
    end

    --pulse 10 times per second
    local serverPulse = timer.performWithDelay( 100, sPulse, 0 )

    local function stopServer()
        timer.cancel( serverPulse )  --cancel timer
        tcp:close()
        for i, v in pairs( clientList ) do
            v:close()
        end
    end
    return stopServer
end

return S
```

server.lua

```js
local S = {}

local socket = require( "socket" )

local clientList = {}
local clientBuffer = {}

S.getIP = function()
    local s = socket.udp()
    s:setpeername( "74.125.115.104", 80 )
    local ip, sock = s:getsockname()
    print( "myIP:", ip, sock )
    return ip
end

S.createServer = function()

    local tcp, err = socket.bind( S.getIP(), 1235 )  --create a server object
    tcp:settimeout( 0 )

    local function sPulse()
        repeat
            local client = tcp:accept()  --allow a new client to connect
            if client then
                print( "found client" )
                client:settimeout( 0 )  --just check the socket and keep going
                --TO DO: implement a way to check to see if the client has connected previously
                --consider assigning the client a session ID and use it on reconnect.
                clientList[#clientList+1] = client
                clientBuffer[client] = { "hello_client" }  --just including something to send below
            end
        until not client

        local ready, writeReady, err = socket.select( clientList, clientList, 0 )
        if err == nil then
            for i = 1, #ready do  --list of clients who are available
                local client = ready[i]
                local allData = {}  --this holds all lines from a given client

                repeat
                    local data, err = client:receive()  --get a line of data from the client, if any
                    --print(data )
                    if data then
                        allData[#allData+1] = data
                    end
                until not data

                if ( #allData > 0 ) then  --figure out what the client said to the server
                    for i, thisData in ipairs( allData ) do
                        print( "thisData: ", thisData )
                        --do stuff with data
                    end
                end
            end

            for sock, buffer in pairs( clientBuffer ) do
                for _, msg in pairs( buffer ) do  --might be empty
                    local data, err = sock:send( msg )  --send the message to the client
                end
            end
        end
    end

    --pulse 10 times per second
    local serverPulse = timer.performWithDelay( 100, sPulse, 0 )

    local function stopServer()
        timer.cancel( serverPulse )  --cancel timer
        tcp:close()
        for i, v in pairs( clientList ) do
            v:close()
        end
    end
    return stopServer
end

return S
```

Comment: When you say no errors in the console, are you running "adb logcat" to look at the device's console log or are you only looking at the Corona simulator log in the terminal/command window?  If its the latter and you're not using adb logcat, this tutorial may help: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was permission i add
"android.permission.INTERNET"
 "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
and the problem is solved